# Will gouuid always generate same value on V5

Tags: go, uuid

I am using the following package - "https://github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid" in my `go` app.

I have a question that I am not sure completely.

Will the value of `uuid.NewV5(uuid.NamespaceURL, []byte("stackoverflow.com"))` will always be same or will it differ system to system?

I mean, if I generate value from `uuid.NewV5(uuid.NamespaceURL, []byte("stackoverflow.com"))` in ubuntu PC and If I generate value from `uuid.NewV5(uuid.NamespaceURL, []byte("stackoverflow.com"))` in centos pc.

Will both of them give the same value? If no, then why?

Sorry for asking the noob question, but I am truly unaware of this and want to learn.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself to check if it gives different values or same on different OS.

Comment: I don't have multiple PC to test it out. Else, why would I have asked it here?

Comment: @user3767643 User Docker to run a container that emulates various OS's. You can also use a virtual machine like VirtualBox, and download images for various OS's. But I would stick to Docker, much easier, faster and in the now.

Comment: If V5 is defined as a SHA1 hash of the provided value, why would it differ between systems? (you can also just look at the code and see what it does https://github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid/blob/179d4d0c4d8d407a32af483c2354df1d2c91e6c3/uuid.go#L113)

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge on `Docker`, plus I don't have heavy configuration PC. Running on 2GB RAM i3 laptop. :(

Comment: @JimB, I looked into the code, but I am not sure, if `UUID` associated with it, will always be same in all machine or not. Since, it is not only sha-1

Comment: @user3767643: I'm not sure what you mean. You're providing the UUID, so if you provide the same one than it will be the same. The `NamespaceURL` value itself is taken from the RFC, so that can't change without breaking compatibility.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "breaking compatibility", like in what situation it can break and I should take care of.

Comment: @user3767643: if you have to worry about a package deviating from the specification, then you probably shouldn't be using it. `NamespaceURL` is defined by the RFC, so it should not change. (even if it were to change, your question about changing between different systems isn't related, since you would presumably still be running the same code and get the same results)

Comment: Ok! I will take a note about it. Thanks a lot for sharing information. (y)

Comment: If they are not equal, it's a bug in the library and you should report it as such. See RFC 4122 section 4.3.

Comment: @user3767643 There is no need to have multiple PC. you can install more than one OS in same PC.

Comment: By the way, I just received the latest Go Newsletter and it mentions the myriads of uuid packages and there now seems to be a group of people trying to maintain [this uuid package](https://github.com/gofrs/uuid) for the future.

Comment: @gonutz - I love this package - https://github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid as it is simple small and best to my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugs aside, any UUIDv5 generator from any library in any language on any operating system on any hardware will generate the same output when given the same input. That's the entire point of UUIDv5.